# why query buider codeigniter is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When I click the save button on the input form, it will run the create method,
And trying to get the data in the database, but it does not work.
Error result, like this:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'E 0001) AS labels FROM `buku` WHERE `id_judul` = '1'' at line 1
>
> SELECT IFNULL(MAX(label_buku), 500 Kin E 0001) AS labels FROM `buku`
>   WHERE `id_judul` = '1'
>
> Filename: models/Buku_model.php
>
> Line Number: 33

Model :

```
 $label      = $judul->klasifikasi.' '.substr($judul->penulis,0,3).' '.substr($judul->judul_buku,0,1).' '.'0001';//500 Kin E 0001
 $id_judul   = $input->id_judul; //1

 $label_buku = $this->db->select("IFNULL(MAX(label_buku),$label) AS labels", false)
                    ->where('id_judul',$id_judul)
                    ->get($this->table)->row();//error
```

Please help me...

Comment: Since, it says, that you have an error in your SQL syntax, you probably should check that. Also, you should only post relevant code to your question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you to improve your question.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I've tried, but still can not work. And I do not know the location of the query error. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 Kin E 0001 needs to be quoted:

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(MAX(label_buku), "500 Kin E 0001") AS labels 
FROM buku 
WHERE id_judul = '1'
```

So in your CodeIgniter query:

```
$label_buku = $this->db->select("IFNULL(MAX(label_buku),\"$label\") AS labels", false)
    ->where('id_judul',$id_judul)
    ->get($this->table)->row();
```